# Changing Value of textfield by button click html javascrift

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTM Javascript I have a button, I want to implement a code whenever I clicked the button it will change the value of my textfield into "123"
then if I clicked it again it will set the value of textfield to "456" then if I clicked the button again it will change again to the value into 123 then if I clicked the button again it will change again to the value into 456

my code for button using custom html

however if Clicked the button it is always displaying '456' no matter what it is not showing '123'.

```js
function myFunction11() {
  document.getElementById("try").value = "123"


  {
    document.getElementById("try").value = "456"
    document.getElementById("d").value = "456"

  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction11();">Try it</button>

Try: <input id="try"> d: <input id="d">
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You do not actually have a test in the code, just bracketed statements. I added inputs for you as you could have done to make a [mcve]

Comment: I **LOVE** `javascrift` !!!

Comment: It's strange to notice how this extra `{` seems to be ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below code helps you

```js
function myFunction11(){
  if(document.getElementById("try").value != "123"){
    document.getElementById("try").value = "123"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("try").value = "456"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="try">
<button onclick="myFunction11();">Try it</button>
```

Comment: DRY? `var try = document.getElementById("try"); try.value=try.value=="123"?"456":"123";`

Answer (score 4):

Must try this solution:

```
<button id="example" data-text-swap="123" data-text-original="456">123</button>

<script>
$("#example").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.text() == el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: To be added to a description: [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) usage, which shortens `if` statements... [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method usage... and jQuery overall .oO(lol *Write less, Do more*.) ;D